# How to politely end a phone call?

Tags: politeness, conversation

Sometimes when someone calls you، you need to end the call because there are no further things to talk about. As you have not initiated the call you expect the other party to end it. But sometimes they don't. How do end the call in such a situation?

Could you provide me with some saying, expressions or common sentences to end a call when you received it.

When I call someone to end a call I just wait for the other person to finish his/her sentence and I say something like "Thanks, that's it. Have a good day!". Maybe there are better ways to end a call even when you have started it. So let me know if you have some other ways to end a call.

Comment: @Brad It's about language. I'm not looking for opinionated answers.

Comment: you could use any of the following, Right then I have to go now. (I am Busy I have to do something else); Is there anything else as I have some "stuff" to do?  Sorry there is someone at the door, speak later. I have another call. My battery is low.

Comment: All your examples are very helpful for language learners. The sentences structure and if they are the common solutions to end a call in the culture.

Comment: Two of Brad's examples sound distinctly British to me. North American equivalents would be, **"Right, I have to go now"** and **"We'll/We can talk later"** (rather than "speak later"). "Stuff" is very informal and would sound rudely dismissive in any but the most casual of contexts; "things" is more neutral.

Answer (score 2):

Some depends on why they called. If they called to chat, it is OK to say, "Well, I need to go now, I have [insert business here} to do. Talk to you later."

If they called with some business in mind, it would be polite and helpful for you to say Something like, "Was that all you needed?" Or if you weren't sure, "So, did that answer your question?" or something indicating that you are thinking the business is done.

If the business isn't done, and can't be done in the time that you have, you can say something like, "I think we'll need to finish this later."

Answer (score 2):

Nice chatting to you. Gotta run now.